# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(n!)^{1/n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(n!)^{1/n}$ converges?

I tried to demonstrate it with the Ratio test but it doesn't simplify anything, which approach is better?

Comment: I see two different variables. Which is the sum with respect to, and which is fixed?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг what do you mean?

Comment: @D.Solfrini There are two variables $n,k$. Which one is the summation over?

Comment: What variable is the sum over? Is it $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)^{\frac 1k}}$$, or $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{(n!)^{\frac 1k}}$$?

Comment: You might try Sterling's approximation?

Comment: sorry I write it wrong! I correct it immediately

Comment: Better. Much better!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because $n! \le n^n, $ $(n!)^{1/n} \le n.$ Thus

$$\frac{1}{(n!)^{1/n}}\ge \frac{1}{n},$$

which implies the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the AM-GM inequality, you can use it here. $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\ge\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1+2+\cdots +n}{n}}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n}}=\dfrac{2}{n+1}\ge\dfrac{1}{n}$. This shows the series in question diverges since the Harmonic series does.